# kendo grid frozen column issue with inline edit

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, frozen-columns

I have a kendo grid with frozen column & inline editing is enabled, first column is frozen and rest all columns are editable and all have checkboxes. the issue is when I edit any row and click edit button of any other row then both rows appear editable. 
I only want the current row to be editable.
Without freezing any column it works but if I used locked:true for any column it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work as expected here: http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@korchev/aSIp

This is the code I've tried:

```
  <div id="grid" style="width: 400px"></div>
  <script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      columns:[{
        field: "foo",
        locked: true,
        width: 100
      }, { field: "bar", width: 200 }, 
               { command: "edit", width: 200 }
      ],
      dataSource: {
        data: [
          { id:1, foo: "foo1", bar: "bar1" },
          { id:1, foo: "foo2", bar: "bar2" }
        ],
        schema: { model: { id: "id" }}
      },
      editable: "inline"
    })
  </script>
```